# how tfidf value is used in k-means clustering

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, k-means, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am using K-means clustering with TF-IDF using sckit-learn library. I understand that K-means uses distance to create clusters and the distance is represented in (x axis value, y axis value) but the tf-idf is a single numerical value. My question is how is this tf-idf value converted into (x,y) value by K-means clustering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TF-IDF isn't a single value (i.e. scalar). For every document, it returns a vector where each value in the vector corresponds to each word in the vocabulary.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csr import csr_matrix

sent1 = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog"
sent2 = "mr brown jumps over the lazy fox"

corpus = [sent1, sent2]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(input=corpus)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(X.todense())
```

[out]:

```
matrix([[0.50077266, 0.35190925, 0.25038633, 0.25038633, 0.25038633,
         0.        , 0.25038633, 0.35190925, 0.50077266],
        [0.35409974, 0.        , 0.35409974, 0.35409974, 0.35409974,
         0.49767483, 0.35409974, 0.        , 0.35409974]])
```

It returns a 2-D matrix where the rows represents the sentences and the columns represent the vocabulary.

```
>>> vectorizer.vocabulary_
{'the': 8,
 'quick': 7,
 'brown': 0,
 'fox': 2,
 'jumps': 3,
 'over': 6,
 'lazy': 4,
 'dog': 1,
 'mr': 5}
```

So when K-means tries to find the distance/similarity between two documents, it's performing the similarity between two rows in the matrix. E.g. assuming the similarity is just the dot product between two rows:

```
import numpy as np
vector1 = X.todense()[0]
vector2 = X.todense()[1]
float(np.dot(vector1, vector2.T))
```

[out]:

```
0.7092938737640962
```

Chris Potts has a nice tutorial on how vector space models like TF-IDF one is created http://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist236/materials/ling236-handout-05-09-vsm.pdf

Comment: Link isn't accessible (Access Forbidden)

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/~cgpotts/teaching/2012-2013/236/materials/ling236-handout-05-09-vsm.pdf